# React Navigation Swapping Icons

Tags: css, reactjs, image, sass, react-navigation

How to change menu icons for both `<NavLink/>` 'active' and CSS `&:hover` states?

#### [SEE GIF: multiple rendering between states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRdaG.gif)

**Navigation Menu with three states:**

1. `inactive-icon` (normal)

   - Show Blue Icon
2. `inactive-icon` `&:Hover` (NavLink/SASS Controlled)

   - Show White Icon & Red background
3. `active active-icon` (React Controlled: swaps elements)

   - Show White Icon & Red background

```
{MENU_CONFIG_LIST.map((page, index) => 
  <NavLink key={'menu-'+index} to={page.route || ''} onClick={()=> page.onClick && page.onClick()}
    className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : '') + ' page' + ((page.exclusiveRoleList === undefined || page.exclusiveRoleList.includes(userRole as RoleEnum)) ? '' : ' hide')}>
    {({ isActive }) => (
      <>
        <img className={isActive ? 'active-icon' : 'active-icon hide'} src={page.activeIcon} />
        <img className={isActive ? 'inactive-icon hide' : 'inactive-icon'} src={page.inactiveIcon} /
        <label className={showMenu ? '' : 'hide'} >{page.label}</label>
     </>
   )}
  </NavLink>
)}
```

SASS Styling:

```
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px auto 16px;

  img {
    grid-column: 1;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .active-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  .inactive-icon {
    display: block;
  }

  &.active,
  &:hover {
    background-color: $red;
    cursor: grab;
  }
}

.active-icon {
  display: block;
}

.inactive-icon {
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;

  &:not(.active-icon):hover {
    display: block;
  }

  &:not(.inactive-icon):hover {
    display: block;
  }
}
```